# Como uno una clase con otra en Python (POO - Herencia Múltiple)

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, herencia

No tengo la mas mínima idea de como hacer para que el calculo de una clase que hice llamada Sueldo (De un archivo llamado Salario), la clase Employee (De un archivo llamado Empleado) pueda usarla...

```
class Sueldo():
    def __init__(self, hTrabajadas):
        self._hTrabajadas = hTrabajadas
    
    #Metodos @property y .setter
        
    def calculoSueldo(self):
        hBase = 40
        sueldoBase = self._hTrabajadas * 300
        hExtra = self._hTrabajadas - hBase
        sueldoExtra = sueldoBase + (hExtra*400)

        if self._hTrabajadas <= 40:
            return f"${sueldoBase}"
        elif self._hTrabajadas > 40:
            return f"${sueldoExtra}"
```

La cuenta de *calculoSueldo()* quiero que pueda usarse en esta Clase:

```
from Persona import Human
from Salario import Sueldo

class Employee(Human, Sueldo):
    def __init__(self, name, surname, age, dni, email, cellphone, hTrabajadas):
        Human.__init__(self, name, surname, age)
        Sueldo.__init__(self, hTrabajadas)
        self._dni = dni
        self._email = email
        self.cellphone = cellphone

    #Metodos @property y .setter

    def showdata(self):
        return f"\nNombre: {self._name}\nApellido: {self._surname}\nEdad: {self._age}\nDNI: {self._dni}\nEmail: {self._email}\nTelefono: {self._cellphone}\nSalario: {self._hTrabajadas}"
```

En showdata(), en la parte de `Salario: {self._hTrabajadas}` , es donde me trabé y no puedo terminar el código

Código de prueba final:

```
from Empleado import Employee

name = input("Nombre: ")
surname = input("Apellido: ")
age = int(input("Edad: "))
dni = int(input("DNI (Sin puntos): "))
email = input("Email: ")
tel = int(input("Telefono: "))
hTrabajadas = int(input("Horas trabajadas: "))

emp1 = Employee(name, surname, age, dni, email, tel, hTrabajadas)
print(emp1.showdata())
```

El problema esta en que puse hTrabajadas y obviamente no me va a devolver la cuenta, pero no se como resolverlo

Quien pueda ayudarme lo agradezco mucho :D

Comment: hazlo con `print(emp1.calculoSueldo())`, probé tu código (quitando todo lo referente a la clase `Human`) y me funcionó perfecto, podrías poner esa clase?

Comment: @Christian gracias :D

Answer (score 1):

Tienes una terrible confusión; mejor empezar de nuevo.

Lo primero es crear las clases, partiendo por la clase `Human`, que debe contener **todos** los atributos propios de la persona; esos que no varían si se cambia de trabajo:

*human.py*

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name, surname, age, dni, email, cellphone):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age
        self.dni = dni
        self.email = email
        self.cellphone = cellphone

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.surname},  {self.name} "
```

Notese que el estándar es definir el método `__str__` para retornar una representación legible del objeto.

La práctica recomenda es **no** imprimir dentro de las clases, sino retornar un string que puede ser impreso, guardado, etc.

*sueldo.py*

La clase sueldo, tal como está definida, es inapropiada, pero dejaremos para el final su discusión. Por ahora la usaremos tal cual

*sueldo.py*

```
class Sueldo:
    def __init__(self, hTrabajadas):
        self._hTrabajadas = hTrabajadas

    def calculoSueldo(self):
        hBase = 40
        sueldoBase = self._hTrabajadas * 300
        hExtra = self._hTrabajadas - hBase
        sueldoExtra = sueldoBase + (hExtra * 400)

        if self._hTrabajadas <= 40:
            return f"${sueldoBase}"
        elif self._hTrabajadas > 40:
            return f"${sueldoExtra}"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self._hTrabajadas}"
```

Finalmente, la clase `Employee`, para lo cual usamos *composición* en lugar de *herencia*. Usamos composición pues queremos *incluir* objetos de otras clases; no *heredar* sus características:

*employee.py*

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, persona, sueldo):
        self.persona = persona
        self.sueldo = sueldo

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Nombre: {self.persona} - Salario: {self.sueldo}"
```

La práctica recomendada es recibir los objetos ya inicializados.

**Demo**

```
from employee import Employee
from human import Human
from sueldo import Sueldo

# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = "José"
    surname = "Lopéz"
    age = 30
    dni = 1000
    email = "jlopez@no.com"
    tel = 349955
    hTrabajadas = 100
    persona = Human(name, surname, age, dni, email, tel)
    sueldo = Sueldo(hTrabajadas)
    emp1 = Employee(persona, sueldo)
    print(emp1)
```

produce:

```
Nombre: Lopéz,  José  - Salario: 100
```

#### Modelamiento

La clase `Sueldo` debería representar las distintas alternativas de salarios en la empresa: salario fijo, por horas, base + comisión, etc., dado que un mismo esquema de salarios se ocupa para un rango de personas.

Defino una clase base con un sólo método, `calcular`, que recibe un empleado, de donde obtiene los datos para calcular el sueldo.

```
from employee import Employee

class Sueldo:
    def calcular(self, empleado):
        print("Error.")
```

El método de la clase base no debería ser llamado nunca. Dejamos un mensaje de alerta para ayudar en la depuración.

Luego puedo definir clases derivadas (usando herencia):

```
class SueldoFijo(Sueldo):
    def __init__(self, sueldo):
        self.sueldo = sueldo

    def calcular(self, empleado):
        return self.sueldo

class SueldoHoras(Sueldo):
    def __init__(self, valor_hora):
        self.valor_hora = valor_hora

    def calcular(self, empleado: Employee):
        return empleado.horasTrabajadas * self.valor_hora

class SueldoComision(Sueldo):
    def __init__(self, base, comision):
        self.base = base
        self.comision = comision

    def calcular(self, empleado: Employee):
        return self.base + empleado.ventas * self.comision
```

Entonces puedo escribir esto:

```
sueldo_secretaria = SueldoFijo(100)
sueldo_programador= SueldoFijo(200)
sueldo_cargador = SueldoHoras(10)
sueldo_vendedor = SueldoComision(20, .5)

secretaria1 = Employe(sec1, sueldo_secretaria)
secretaria12 = Employe(sec2, sueldo_secretaria)
vendedor1 = Employee(vend1, sueldo_vendedor)
```

La clase `Employee` ahora puede definir un método genérico para calcular cualquier tipo de suelo, simplemente ejecutando el método `calcular` del objeto `sueldo` recibido.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo. La voy a rehacer toda y a aplicar lo que me dijiste :D